# I can not choose RegEx

Tags: html, regex, asp-classic, tags

```
<p[^>]*>([a-zA-Z0-9_\W]*)\:<\/p>.*?(<blockquote[^>]*>).*?<\/blockquote>

<p> demo demo:</p>  <p ><img src="http://demo.com/123.jpg" width="100%"/>   <br/>   <em>Credit: demo2 demo2 </em></p>   <p >here1 here1:</p>    <blockquote cite="here1">   <p><em>demo3. demo3 demo3 demo3:</em></p>   </blockquote>   <p >demo4 demo4:</p>    <p ><img src="http://demo.com/1234.jpg" width="100%"/>  <br/>   <em>demo5 demo 5 demo5</em></p> <p >demo6 demo6:</p>    <blockquote cite="demo6">   <p><em>demo7 demo7<br/>
```

The above pattern is malfunctioning. Where can I make mistakes. The pattern I wrote above, I can not choose what I want in a sentence. Help request.

I want to get results:

```
<p >here1 here1:</p>    <blockquote cite="here1">   <p><em>demo3. demo3 demo3 demo3:</em></p>   </blockquote>
```

[I added that I will ask for a sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQQL.png)

Comment: Please include a *text* sample, not an image.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I added image. See you please: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQQL.png

Comment: and I add the code as text.

Comment: Use an html parser not a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to use regex here, this may work for you:

```
<p[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/p>).)+)<\/p>\s*<blockquote[^>]*>(.*?)<\/blockquote>
```

the relevant part is `((?:(?!<\/p>).)+)`: in English, it says, "look ahead to make sure there's no `</p>`, then grab one character, and repeat this (until the next `</p>`)". In this way, no multiple sibling `<p>`'s (or indeed, nested `<p>`'s) could be matched, which is what is happening with your original pattern: `<p[^>]*>([a-zA-Z0-9_\W]*)\:<\/p>` will match, wrongly in this context: `<p>one paragraph</p><p>second paragraph</p>`. I also specified only spaces (`\s*`, not `.*?`) between the `<p>` and the `<blockquote>`, so you only match the *preceding* `<p>`.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY5rH1/4)

Comment: Super. Thank you very much sweaver.